# POST value radio button using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

First of thanks for taking the time to read my question. I know (and SO told me when writing the subject) this question has been asked a ton of times. But mine is slightly different. I have a **working** AJAX script that uses a `dropdown menu`. But I would like to convert the `dropdown` into a `radio button menu`.

The script (which I found on the internet) is also used for pagination so, if at all possible, I would love to keep the script intact. And only change the `var sortBy = $('#sortBy').val;` part. Because the script works like a charm for me.

I've been reading up on all kinds of tips/answers from other SO users but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the AJAX script:

```
function searchFilter(page_num) {
    page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
    var keywords = $('#keywords').val();
    var sortBy = $('#sortBy').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/getData.php',
        data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords+'&sortBy='+sortBy,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading-overlay').show();
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#posts_content').html(html);
            $('.loading-overlay').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<select id="sortBy" onchange="searchFilter()">
    <option value="">Sort By</option>
    <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
    <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

And last but not leased the getData.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    //Include pagination class file
    include('navigation.php');

    //Include database configuration file
    include('server.php');

    $start = !empty($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:0;
    $limit = 6;

    //set conditions for search
    $whereSQL = $orderSQL = '';
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $sortBy = $_POST['sortBy'];
    if(!empty($keywords)){
        $whereSQL = "WHERE title LIKE '%".$keywords."%'";
    }
    if(!empty($sortBy)){
        $orderSQL = " ORDER BY id ".$sortBy;
    }else{
        $orderSQL = " ORDER BY id DESC ";
    }

    //get number of rows
    $queryNum = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as postNum FROM MirrorWebProductsExpanded WHERE cat = '1' ".$orderSQL);
```

I've tried to change the `var sortBy = $('#sortBy').val();` to `van sortBy = $('input[name=select]:checked');` with the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio"  name="select" value=""/>Radio 1
<input type="radio"  name="select" value="1"/>Radio 2
<input type="radio"  name="select" value="2"/>Radio 3
```

But this doesn't work. It just selects the radio button and nothing more. I've tried using an `alert` function:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '[name="select"]' , function(){
    var val = $('[name="select"]:checked').val();
    alert(val);
});
```

But again, no alert... any help, on how to sent the radio button value trough AJAX. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `'input[name="select"]'` instead of `'[name="select"]'` that was your mistake see below your code working

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'input[name="select"]', function() {
    searchFilter($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1" />Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2" />Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3" />Radio 3
```

**EDIT**

An ideal way would be to include another `param` to your function `searchfilter()` along with `page_num` say `sortBy`and looking at your function it seems like page_num can be optional so lets move that `param` to last and add a new `param` named `sortBy` in the the start , this way you can call the function like `searchfiletr(sortBy)` if you do not want to pass the `page_num`.

your function will looik like this

```
function searchFilter(sortBy,page_num) {
    page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
    var keywords = $('#keywords').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/getData.php',
        data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords+'&sortBy='+sortBy,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading-overlay').show();
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#posts_content').html(html);
            $('.loading-overlay').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Right now I get the alert. But how do I 'save' the value and post it to the AJAX script? Because for this to work, I had to place it the code `out` of the **function** in my opening post.

Comment: well why donot you call the ajax function inside this `onchange` function and pass the selected value to the function `searchFilter`, I just updated the answer ,

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've copied your updated code above the function `searchFilter` and when I select a radio button I get: `page_num is not defined`. I'm sorry for this, but I'm kind of new to this function in a function :)

Comment: I updated my answer again and added the description for this ,refresh your page

Comment: I did, and then again as you updated your answer again (thanks a million for your help btw!). But I still get `page_num is not defined`. Maybe I should give up and stick to the dropdown :( Or if you're still willing to help?

Comment: have you changed the order of the params, ? I do not think so, I added the function in the end of my answer, it should work. with the format `searchFilter(sortBy,page_num);`

Comment: just refresh the page and see the latest answer

Comment: ahhh! you must be including the `page_num` in the call , darn that was just to show the demonstration :D , you do not have to send it. see I updated the code snippet again , sorry that was mymistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159602/discussion-between-ali-aslam-and-jay-oh).

Comment: WOW, this is working! Thank you, thank you! Now I just have to set the correct values... and I think where up and running! Thanks again, a million times and for your quick replays!!!

Comment: no problem friend @Jay-oh , glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You almost nailed it. Just a small change:

```
 <input type="radio" class="dummy"  name="select" value=""/>Radio 1
 <input type="radio" class="dummy" name="select" value="1"/>Radio 2
 <input type="radio" class="dummy" name="select" value="2"/>Radio 3
```

I added dummy class to your radios and this is how JQuery looks like

```
<script >
    $(function () {
        $('.dummy').change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            alert(val);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tested and working.

```js
 $(function () {
            $('.dummy').change(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                alert(val);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="dummy"  name="select" value=""/>Radio 1
     <input type="radio" class="dummy" name="select" value="1"/>Radio 2
     <input type="radio" class="dummy" name="select" value="2"/>Radio 3
```